# Cannot convert 'this' pointer to Class&

Tags: c++

Can someone tell why i'm getting this error when compling this class?

```
class C
{
public:
    void func(const C &obj)
    {
       //body
    }

private:
    int x;
};

void func2(const C &obj)
{
    obj.func(obj);
}

int main() { /*no code here yet*/}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The C::func() method doesn't promise that it won't modify the object, it only promises that it won't modify its argument.  Fix:

```
   void func(const C &obj) const
    {
       // don't change any this members or the compiler complains
    }
```

Or make it a static function.  Which sure sounds like it should be when it takes a C object as an argument.

Comment: Good answer. Trying to make the point even clearer: Since `func2` takes a `const C &` (ie. a reference to a `const C`), it means that the function cannot modify this object instance. This constraint is passed on to the called member function `C::func`: it is expected to not modify the object instance; thus the required `const` in the declaration.

Comment: Ok, but Why does it say cannot convert to C& ?

Comment: It's not a great error message.  My compiler says "Cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const C' to 'C &'".  Which doesn't win any prizes either perhaps but does make it clear that a const correctness problem is the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You need to mark `C::func(const C &obj)` as const as you're calling it from a const object. The correct signature would look like this:

```
void func(const C& obj) const
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in `func2()` you're calling a non-const function (`C::func()`) using a const object.

Change the signature of `C::func()` to:

```
void func(const C &obj) const
{
    // whatever...
}
```

so that it can be called with const objects.

Answer (score 1):

Because:

```
this
```

is a **const** pointer to current obj.

Therefore you can either make the func to be const:

```
class C
{
public:
    void func(const C &obj) const
    {
       //body
    }

private:
    int x;
};

void func2(const C &obj)
{
    obj.func(obj);
}

int main() { 
return 0;
}
```

OR

you can remove the constness of the **this** pointer like this:

```
class C
{
public:
    void func(const C &obj)
    {
       //body
    }

private:
    int x;
};

void func2(const C &obj)
{
    (const_cast<C &>(obj)).func(obj);
}

int main() { 
return 0;
}
```

Hope that helps.